# How can I run PHP application inside .net core application

Tags: php, .net, iis, integration

I am trying to integrate .net and php applications. I want to run php application inside core .net application but not working with IIS 10.

PHP 5.6 is installed in in c:\ drive and my source repositories are there in d:\ drive.

Can I run .net as parent application and php as child application.

From .net app onclick button calls below method which open php application and from that it should send some data back to .net window.

```
 function invoke_reporting() {
        var newwindow = window.open("http://192.168.17.109/TestCopy_Report1/templates/ct-head");
     }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "_run PHP application inside .net core application"_? How are you expecting those two applications to interact?

Comment: edited my question

Comment: That's javascript, not .NET. If you want to use the result of that request on the current page, you could make an Ajax request. Since that code happens client side, it won't matter if the page was generated through .NET, PHP or any other language. It's simply a JS request to a URL.

Answer (score 0):

you should `curl` (or via whatever client) data from the php endpoint. rather than showing the PHP page then passing the data back to .net

Comment: can you give me an example of this